# wifi not working( Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: wireless

I am getting errors while running  these command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

---

```
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/home/greenseek/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-devtrace.o' failed
make[6]: *** [/home/greenseek/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-devtrace.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:581: recipe for target '/home/greenseek/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi' failed
make[5]: *** [/home/greenseek/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:581: recipe for target '/home/greenseek/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/greenseek/backports-20151120/drivers/net/wireless] Error 2
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/home/greenseek/backports-20151120' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/greenseek/backports-20151120] Error 2
Makefile.build:6: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile.real:88: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: The title of your post does not match the body. I assume you are following a guide you've found somewhere to fix your wifi, but please clarify that. Wireless issues are hardware-specific so please provide details of the device that is not working. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) for the kind of info needed

Comment: Whatever problem you are having won't be solved by installing a driver suite that is 2 1/2 years *older* than the default driver in 17.10. Please tell us what problem you are having. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.